# record video with AVFoundation with custom dimensions?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, avfoundation

I am recording an MOV file using AVFoundation but im having trouble finding out how to change the dimensions of the video. I have `videoGravity` property of `captureVideoPreviewLayer` set to `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` and the `UIView` showing the preview layer has custom dimensions (not the same aspect ratio of the screen).

Recording works fine but the dimensions of the recorded video are the same as the aspect ratio of the screen. How can i record with the aspect ratio of the UIView or the preview layer?

Comment: Do you want to crop the video to the new dimensions, scale it or morph it?

Comment: @MobileOverlord i guess both crop and scale up since GravityResizeAspectFill does just that

Comment: @URLArenzo im recording from the camera

Answer (score 3):

Here is best sample code to record video using AVFoundation

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110

In File: `RosyWriterVideoProcessor.m`

Method Name

```
- (BOOL) setupAssetWriterVideoInput:(CMFormatDescriptionRef)currentFormatDescription
```

In videoCompressionSettings you can change dimension, hope this will help you.