# iOS Record Square Video

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

I am looking for a way to record video in a square aspect ratio only.

This is very similar to the way Instagram or Path allow you to only take "square photos", but I am looking for a way to do it with video recording?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9411826/1799647. It works for me. 
But if you are using autolayout in storyboard, you need to add `[previewView layoutIfNeeded]` in - `(void)viewDidLoad` of your camera view controller. Otherwise height and width of camera view bounds will be zero and error will occur.

Comment: u will get not square image from delegate